# Paypal Checkout Button Not Redirecting

Tags: magento, paypal, magento2

I've added paypal as a checkout option to our Magento 2 website, entered the API info required from the Paypal account and set to 'payment action' - 'Sale'

However when you click the checkout with Paypal option on site www.bollo.store , it does not redirect to Paypal to make the payment, the button appears to do nothing.

Any tips much appreciated.

Kind Regards,

N

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with flushing cache and do with static deploy?

First try this to clean cache, generated and preprocessed code and static content on frontend

```
rm -rf var/di/* generated/* var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/frontend/*
```

then this to do static deploy for en_US, alternatively you can do static deploy without defining language (en_US in this case).

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US
```

Link to official documentation for static deploy on Magento 2.2
 http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Comment: I've updated my answer, first line is for removing cache and second could solve problem. This is just first basic attempt for fix.